# Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. (cannot login and signup with authentication in firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I got a problem of cannot signup and also login (only able to sign up twice and after that couldn't do that anymore). Below are my codes:

this is login activity:

```
package com.example.mae_assignment

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Patterns
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser

class Login : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.login)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val btnSignUp = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSignUp)
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this, SignUp::class.java))
            finish()
        }

        val btnLogin = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSignIn)
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener{
            doLogin()
        }
    }

    private fun doLogin() {
        val password = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.txtPwd)
        val email = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.txtUE)
        if (email.text.toString().isEmpty()){
            email.error = "Please enter email."
            email.requestFocus()
            return
        }
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email.text.toString()).matches()){
            email.error = "Please enter email."
            email.requestFocus()
            return
        }
        if (password.text.toString().isEmpty()){
            password.error = "Please enter password."
            password.requestFocus()
            return
        }

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.text.toString().trim(), password.text.toString().trim())
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task->
                if (task.isSuccessful){
                    val user =auth.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                }else{
                    val myToast = Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Login failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    myToast.show()
                    updateUI(null)
                }
            }
    }
    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        updateUI(currentUser)
    }

    private fun updateUI(currentUser:FirebaseUser?){
        if(currentUser != null){
            startActivity(Intent(this, Home::class.java))
            val myToast = Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Login successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            myToast.show()
        } else {
            val myToast = Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Login failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            myToast.show()
        }
    }

}
```

this is signup activity:

```
package com.example.mae_assignment

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Patterns
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class SignUp : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.signup)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val btnCreateAcc = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnCreateAccount)
        btnCreateAcc.setOnClickListener{

            signup()
        }
    }

    private fun signup(){
        val txtpassword = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.txtpassword)
        val txtemail = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.txtemail)
        if (txtemail.text.toString().isEmpty()){
            txtemail.error = "Please enter email."
            txtemail.requestFocus()
            return
        }
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(txtemail.text.toString()).matches()){
            txtemail.error = "Please enter email."
            txtemail.requestFocus()
            return
        }
        if (txtpassword.text.toString().isEmpty()){
            txtpassword.error = "Please enter password."
            txtpassword.requestFocus()
            return
        }

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txtemail.text.toString().trim(), txtpassword.text.toString().trim())
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task->
                if (task.isSuccessful){
                    startActivity(Intent(this, Login::class.java))
                    finish()
                }else{
                    val myToast = Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Sign up failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    myToast.show()
                }
            }
    }
}


package com.example.mae_assignment

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Patterns
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class SignUp : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.signup)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val btnCreateAcc = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnCreateAccount)
        btnCreateAcc.setOnClickListener{

            signup()
        }
    }

    private fun signup(){
        val txtpassword = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.txtpassword)
        val txtemail = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.txtemail)
        if (txtemail.text.toString().isEmpty()){
            txtemail.error = "Please enter email."
            txtemail.requestFocus()
            return
        }
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(txtemail.text.toString()).matches()){
            txtemail.error = "Please enter email."
            txtemail.requestFocus()
            return
        }
        if (txtpassword.text.toString().isEmpty()){
            txtpassword.error = "Please enter password."
            txtpassword.requestFocus()
            return
        }

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txtemail.text.toString().trim(), txtpassword.text.toString().trim())
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task->
                if (task.isSuccessful){
                    startActivity(Intent(this, Login::class.java))
                    finish()
                }else{
                    val myToast = Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Sign up failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    myToast.show()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And this is the gradle build:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is gradle build (app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mae_assignment"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

Please help to solve this TQVM. I have been doing this for like 2 weeks, sigh.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Could you please provide an error message or describe what "couldn't do that anymore" means in your case?